# Spring JPA, не работают параметры в @Query, если таблицы связаны не по первичному ключу

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Вот связанные модели:

```
@Entity
public class Partner {

...
    @Column(name = "pair_id", unique = true)
    private Integer pairId;
...
}


@Entity
public class ClientOrder {

...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "partner_id", referencedColumnName = "pair_id")
    private Partner partner;
...
}
```

Вот метод репозитория:

```
@Query("select co.user from ClientOrder co where co.partner = ?1")
List<UserDevice> findAllByClientOrders(Partner partner);
```

При попытке выполнить метод, в запрос подставляется значение null, хотя partner содержит объект. В логах хибернейт выводит:

```
TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [null]
```

Почему хибернейт не использует поля, описанные в @JoinColumn?

Comment: Лучше всегда использовать связь именно по первичным ключам. поправьте     @JoinColumn(name = "partner_id") и запрос
@Query("select co.user from ClientOrder co where co.partner.pairId = ?1")
List<UserDevice> findAllByClientOrders(Integer pairId);

Comment: Естественно, лучше. Но обстоятельства иногда не позволяют. Хотелось бы понять, в чем проблема в данном случае.